# SVN ignore certain files only one directory level below

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive, svnignore

I have a certain gradle multiproject on svn. When I check out to local directory and do `gradle eclipse`, .classpath and .project files are created in each subproject directory (directory structure below) which should be further ignored by svn.

```
myproject
  -A
    -src (several directories under src)
    -lib (several directories under lib)
    -.classpath
    -.project
  -B
    -src (several directories under src)
    -lib (several directories under lib)
    -.classpath
    -.project
  -C
    -src (several directories under src)
    -lib (several directories under lib)
    -.classpath
    -.project
  -build.gradle
```

When using svn:ignore property as so `svn propset svn:ignore -R -F .svnignore .` (contents of .svnignore file below) it affects all the sub-directories as required however it also affects all the sub-sub directories and changes their property which is not required (i.e./src and ./lib and every level under that). Now what I am trying to do is only ignore .classpath and .project one directory level below, i.e. each sub-project and no deeper than that, something like `svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore .*\`

Contents of .svnignore file:

> .classpath
>
> .project

Answer (score 1):

1. Why you don't want to have 3 separate propset for A,B,C only (non-recursively)?
2. Perform partial checkout|update of myproject (with --depth 'immediates'), execute your old `svn propset`, get missing objects|return depth state by update with `--set-depth 'immediates'`